# Convert a time string into a decimal number of hours?

Tags: python

How can I convert a string like "12:30" or "5:51:23" into a decimal number representing the amount of elapsed hours in Python?

Comment: The current Question and the one marked as duplicate addresses different Issues. The Solution posted for the duplicate question does not address incomplete time string ex "12:30". Voting to reopen

Answer (score 3):

Fairly simple string-splitting and math:

```
def time_string_to_decimals(time_string):
    fields = time_string.split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    seconds = fields[2] if len(fields) > 2 else 0.0
    return float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0) + (float(seconds) / pow(60.0, 2)
```

If only a single number is given like `"3"`, this will return `3.0`. If two colon-delimited values are given like `"4:57"`, this will return `4.95`. If three colon-delimited values are given like `"14:36:27"`, this will return `14.6075`.

Answer (score 2):

Possible Solution

```
>>> time_st = ["12:30" , "5:51:23"]
>>> HMS = [60*60, 60, 1]
>>> for t in time_st:
    dec_time = sum(a * b for a,b in zip(HMS, map(int, t.split(":"))))
    dec_time /= 3600.
    print "{} = {}".format(t, dec_time)


12:30 = 12.5
5:51:23 = 5.85638888889
00:00 = 0.0
23:59 = 23.9833333333
```

Comment: Changing HMS to [1, 1.0/60, 1.0/3600], dec_time will be in hours. Division by 3600 may not be required.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> float('5:51:23'.split(':')[0])
5.0
```

Comment: From the self-answer from the OP, I am guessing this is not sufficient.

Comment: Maybe, ultimately he will decide if the answer is what he wants. In this case I'm strictly following the requirement and the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).